# React intermittent memory leak from a scroll-to-top component

Tags: reactjs, scroll, memory-leaks, use-effect

While debugging I've noticed within the console, I'm getting the warning message of:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

However, the warning is only thrown minimally and I cannot seem to figure out how to replicate the issue when navigating and scrolling through my site and using the component button.

code:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'

// React Icons
import { BiUpArrowAlt } from 'react-icons/bi'

// Context
import { ThemeContext } from '../../context/ThemeProvider'

const ScrollTop = () => {
  const { windowWidth, windowHeight } = useContext(ThemeContext)
  const [scrollTop, setScrollTop] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = () => setScrollTop(window.pageYOffset <= 0 ? 0 : window.pageYOffset)
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
  }, [scrollTop])

  return windowHeight / 2 <= scrollTop && windowWidth > 991 ? (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-lg-4">
        <div
          aria-hidden="true"
          className="backTop"
          onClick={() => window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })}
        >
          <BiUpArrowAlt className="icon" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    ''
  )
}

export default ScrollTop
```

### Research

Tried to find if I can learn why this might be occurring after reading:

- [React useEffect causing: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954385/react-useeffect-causing-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-comp)
- [How to fix React WArning : Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71258604/how-to-fix-react-warning-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-co)
- [Warning : Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71766420/warning-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component-this-is)
- [How to stop memory leak in useEffect hook react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58038008/how-to-stop-memory-leak-in-useeffect-hook-react)
- [How to fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69733784/how-to-fix-cancel-all-subscriptions-and-asynchronous-tasks-in-a-useeffect-clean)
- [Memory leak warning in react component using hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69407023/memory-leak-warning-in-react-component-using-hooks)

Per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258806/1952287) and [Dan Abramov](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/22114) it mentions that this would be removed in the future from likely false positives.

Since I'm unable to replicate this error, is this likely a false positive, or is there something I am misunderstanding and can improve on in my `useEffect` that could be firing the warning?